# Parsing cyrillic symbols from json

Tags: java, android, json, utf-8, cyrillic

Server send correct json via socket to my android app. This json contain some values with cyrillic letters. App reads socket with inpitStreamReader:

```
BufferedReader socketInput = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                    String answer = socketInput.readLine();
```

And after reading i've got this string:

```
{"STORAGE":"USER_FOUND","REGISTRATION_DATE":1466167435,"NAME":"���"}
```

How can i tune inputStreamReader for correct encoding cyrillic letters.

Comment: Are you sure that server sends text in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Yeap - 100% correct

Comment: Where do you see that � symbol? Console, file, debugger, etc?

Comment: console, android UI

Comment: What are you using for the server ? PHP ?

Comment: Java 8 application, Windows 7 OS (testing environment)

Comment: In Android, try change `String answer = socketInput.readLine();` to `String answer = new String(socketInput.readLine().getBytes(), "UTF-8");`

Comment: Try to write received bytes to a file and see what it contains with Notepad++ or something similar. May be something wrong with console output.

Comment: Just tried this stuff - new String(socketInput.readLine().getBytes(), "UTF-8") - same results. I think that wrong encoding takes place in readLine(), and in that case we take bytes from already encoded string.

Comment: You have tried to run this application ? Older versions of ADT don't support other languages than english, try put this response on an Toast for debug proposes

Comment: I run this code on fully functional app on Android 4.4 - this string passed to TextView - and i see same ���

Comment: to new String ... is needed that the characters are not escaped, if it's try send then without

Comment: You are setting the encode on buffered reader try just ` socketInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));`

Comment: Tested - without explicit charset - same result

Comment: That's wierd - in my another app i read bytes from socket with SocketChannel.read() in UTF-8 encoding - and all cyrrilic characters shown properly

Comment: Yes, this should be working, maybe the problem is in your server encode

Comment: Just tried set explicit encode to Utf-8 on server side - got ??? instead of ���

Comment: And also this string pulled from MySql table with utf8 default collation

Comment: Your code is fine. Check `String answer = "\u0431\u0431\u0432";`. Font issue?